# About Form use in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my Laravel error:

```
FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 6376:
Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
in compiled.php line 6376
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError(array('type' => '1', 'message' => 'Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found', 'file' => '/home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php', 'line' => '6376')) in compiled.php line 1721
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
```

And my console error:

```
Generating autoload files
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /home
/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php on line 6376
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/nl/Laravel/artisan:0
PHP   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() /home/nl/Laravel/artisan
:36
PHP   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap() /home/nl/Laravel/vend
or/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:92
PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith() /home/nl/Laravel/ven
dor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:195
PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders->bootstrap() /home/nl
/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:1307
PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerConfiguredProviders() /home/
nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:1758
PHP   7. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load() /home/nl/Laravel/stora
ge/framework/compiled.php:1404
PHP   8. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest() /home/nl/La
ravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:6338
PHP   9. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider() /home/nl/Lar
avel/storage/framework/compiled.php:6362
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'Th
e stream or file "/home/nl/Laravel/storage/logs/laravel-2015-04-20.log" could no
t be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /home/nl/Laravel/stora
ge/framework/compiled.php:12372
Stack trace:
#0 /home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php(12431): Monolog\Handler\Strea
mHandler->write(Array)
#1 /home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php(12313): Monolog\Handler\Rotat
ingFileHandler->write(Array)
#2 /home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php(12081): Monolog\Handler\Abstr
actProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#3 /home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php(12179): Monolog\Logger->addRe
cord(400, 'exception 'Symf...', Array)
#4 /home/nl/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exception
s/Handler.php(47): Monolog\Logger->error('exception 'Symf...')
#5 /home/nl/Laravel/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(27): Illuminate\Foundation\Except
ions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorExceptio
n))
#6  in /home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php on line 12372
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/nl/Laravel/artisan:0
PHP   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() /home/nl/Laravel/artisan
:36
PHP   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap() /home/nl/Laravel/vend
or/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:92
PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith() /home/nl/Laravel/ven
dor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:195
PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders->bootstrap() /home/nl
/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:1307
PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerConfiguredProviders() /home/
nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:1758
PHP   7. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load() /home/nl/Laravel/stora
ge/framework/compiled.php:1404
PHP   8. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest() /home/nl/La
ravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:6338
PHP   9. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider() /home/nl/Lar
avel/storage/framework/compiled.php:6362
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned wi
th an error



  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'  
   not found in /home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php on line 6376   
  PHP Stack trace:                                                             
  PHP   1. {main}() /home/nl/Laravel/artisan:0                                 
  PHP   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() /home/nl/Laravel/ar  
  tisan:36                                                                     
  PHP   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap() /home/nl/Laravel  
  /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:92    
  PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith() /home/nl/Larave  
  l/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:195  
  PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders->bootstrap() /ho  
  me/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:1307                            
  PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerConfiguredProviders() /  
  home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:1758                          
  PHP   7. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load() /home/nl/Laravel/  
  storage/framework/compiled.php:1404                                          
  PHP   8. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest() /home/  
  nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:6338                               
  PHP   9. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider() /home/n  
  l/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:6362                                
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with messag  
  e 'The stream or file "/home/nl/Laravel/storage/logs/laravel-2015-04-20.log  
  " could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /home/n  
  l/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:12372                               
  Stack trace:                                                                 
  #0 /home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php(12431): Monolog\Handler\  
  StreamHandler->write(Array)                                                  
  #1 /home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php(12313): Monolog\Handler\  
  RotatingFileHandler->write(Array)                                            
  #2 /home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php(12081): Monolog\Handler\  
  AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)                                     
  #3 /home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php(12179): Monolog\Logger->  
  addRecord(400, 'exception 'Symf...', Array)                                  
  #4 /home/nl/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exce  
  ptions/Handler.php(47): Monolog\Logger->error('exception 'Symf...')          
  #5 /home/nl/Laravel/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(27): Illuminate\Foundation\E  
  xceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErr  
  orException))                                                                
  #6  in /home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php on line 12372         
  PHP Stack trace:                                                             
  PHP   1. {main}() /home/nl/Laravel/artisan:0                                 
  PHP   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() /home/nl/Laravel/ar  
  tisan:36                                                                     
  PHP   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap() /home/nl/Laravel  
  /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:92    
  PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith() /home/nl/Larave  
  l/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:195  
  PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders->bootstrap() /ho  
  me/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:1307                            
  PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerConfiguredProviders() /  
  home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:1758                          
  PHP   7. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load() /home/nl/Laravel/  
  storage/framework/compiled.php:1404                                          
  PHP   8. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest() /home/  
  nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:6338                               
  PHP   9. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider() /home/n  
  l/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php:6362
```

I refer to [this tutorial](http://laravel.io/forum/09-20-2014-html-form-class-not-found-in-laravel-5), and am following these steps:

1."illuminate/html": "5.*"

2.Run: composer update

3.Add to the app.php providers array:

```
  'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

4.Add to the app.php aliases array:

'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',

but still not work, someone could give some advice?

Comment: Try running composer dump.  And by the way verify you really have the files under `vendor\illuminate\html

Comment: Please provide your errors as text in the question, not screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Please provide your console error as text also - screenshots are not necessary here.

Comment: thanks everyone , I use   "composer require illuminate/html" solve this problem

Comment: @nlstduio you should post it as an answer of your own question... it worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I've found there is a bit of an issue with that library that composer requires - try changing:

```
"illuminate/Html" : "5.0.*"
```

To..

```
"Illuminate/Html": "5.0.*@dev"
```

in the composer.json in the root of your laravel project.

Comment: @halfer whoops. Edited.

Comment: thanks a lot , but still error ...><

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing laravel/framework (v5.0.27)
  - Installing laravel/framework (v5.0.28)
    Downloading: 100%         

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /home/nl/Laravel/storage/framework/compiled.php on line 6376
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/nl/Laravel/artisan:0
PHP   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() /home/nl/Laravel/artisan:36
PHP   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap() /home/nl/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:92
PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith() /home/nl/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:195

Comment: thanks everyone , I use   "composer require illuminate/html" solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I fall this problem,solve this and wrote a blog about it.For use laravel html helper you need to require this dependency in your composesr.josn file and need to require those file.For full process follow this url http://www.kingpabel.com/laravel-html-helper/